# Put link in console.log(). Node.js

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, console

I would like to do something like this:

```
console.log('Your server available at <a href="localhost:3000"> localhost:3000 </a>');
```

But unfortunately node console doesn't recognize 'a' tag.

Are any ideas how to put link in node console?

Answer (score 22):

There is no way you can make an HTML tag interpreted by your the terminal, because your terminal has no ideas what html is.

You can just display a URL in console output like
`console.log('Your server available at http://localhost:3000`

Most modern terminals will automatically parse it as a URL (if you put a valid URL there)

For example, Mac default terminal redirects to valid URL from console output if you double-click on it while holding `Cmd`

Comment: Are you familiar with how tools like Browsersync accomplish this then?

Comment: @alchemist95, if you're using that package, I would recommend to using the one that it's wrapping. https://github.com/sindresorhus/ansi-escapes

Answer (score 2):

console.log in Node renders text in the console window (command prompt in Windows) which does not know how to interpret html tags.  I am afraid that you would not be able to do that unless you find a 3rd party plugin (if such plugin even exists) that allow that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this. Some terminals started supporting links not long time ago. I think it was around 2017.

You will find more info here: https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda