# How to console.log short links in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, console.log

In Visual Studio Code, when I `console.log(something)`, in the Console on the right side, I get a link to the file and line on the right side. If I hover over this link I get the full path. When I CTRL-click this link I will be taken to the corresponding location in my code.

> debug console example
> [image]

How do I output such a custom link with `console.log()` or any other function so it is visible as only a short name and when I hover over it it shows the full path and when I CTRL-click this link I am taken to the corresponding location in my code?

I tried stuff like `file://path/to/file` or `vscode://file/path/to/file`, but it always prints out the full path which takes a lot of space in the debug line.

How do I only get a single alias to the link like the built-in debugger console can do it?

Answer (score 0):

That file source indicator you are referring to isn't something that you can create or control to your heart's content with a `console.log`. It's part of the debugging facilities provided by VS Code and (I'd wager) the debug-support provided by the JavaScript/TypeScript language extension. What is under your control is the content you `console.log`, which is shown on the left side of your screenshot.

As far as creating links with custom text in the debug output panel, I don't think that's possible. There's no NodeJS-provided mechanism for doing things like this (see [Put link in console.log(). Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36295789/11107541)) because it's pretty terminal dependent. Terminals may provide mechanisms for creating links with custom text, but again, the design of that mechnaism is up to them. As for VS Code's debug output panel, it does automatic detection of certain links like `https://` and `file://`, and I believe it does do detection for relative file paths to files in the workspace, but doesn't provide a user-facing mechanism for customizing the visible text of links. You can however look into designing and writing an extension to do these kinds of things. I think you would do it by writing a [`DocumentLinkProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentLinkProvider).